# Android asynctask on listview

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listadapter

so I have a problem populating a listActivity during the onPostExecute method.
The result list of SingleData is correct... Then I use a custom adapter to bind to the android.R.id.list...

but it gives me error... and I really don't understand why... 
so here's the code of the adapter.. :

```
private class RequestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SingleData> {

    private int _resource;
    private LayoutInflater _inflater;
    private Context _context;

    public RequestAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<SingleData> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        _resource = textViewResourceId;
        _context = context;
        _inflater = LayoutInflater.from(_context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = (ListView)_inflater.inflate(_resource,null);
        SingleData sdd = getItem(position);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imagePlaceHolder_IV);
        iv.setImageBitmap(sdd.thumbIMG);

        TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.createdAt_TV);
        tv.setText(sdd.timeStamp);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return convertView;         
    }

}
```

and here is the onPostExecute:

```
private class DownloadTheImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<SingleData>> {

    private Context _ctx;

    public DownloadTheImages(Context ctx) {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }

     protected void onPostExecute(List<SingleData> result) {             

         ListView mainLV = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
         mainLV.setAdapter(new RequestAdapter(_ctx, R.layout.single_row, result));

     }

    protected List<SingleData> doInBackground(Void... params) {
              ..... 
             ....
              }
       }
```

and the LOGCAT:

```
10-20 15:02:55.166: E/AndroidRuntime(761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 15:02:55.166: E/AndroidRuntime(761): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 15:02:55.166: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at com.mimiedesign.dingle.PictureStreamViewer$DownloadTheImages.onPostExecute(PictureStreamViewer.java:103)
10-20 15:02:55.166: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at com.mimiedesign.dingle.PictureStreamViewer$DownloadTheImages.onPostExecute(PictureStreamViewer.java:1)
10-20 15:02:55.166: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
10-20 15:02:55.166: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
10-20 15:02:55.166: E/AndroidRuntime(761):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
```

any clue?... thanks..

THESE ARE THE NEWER ERRORS:

```
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
10-20 16:32:56.615: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines are causing this issue.

```
     RequestAdapter adapter; // This will be member variable
     ListView mainLV = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
     mainLV.setAdapter(new RequestAdapter(_ctx, R.layout.single_row, result));
```

Move these lines in onCreate() and initialize result before instantiating Adapter then, in onPostExecute simply add values to 'result' ArrayList and call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(). Avoid finding views in onPostExecute() or onProgressUpdate().

Comment: now it gives me error, on the setAdapter method at the beginning ... I guess it's becaseu in the getView of teh adapter there's no check if the obecjt upon which doing getItem is null or empty... any advice how to check that?

Comment: Before setting the adapter you need to initialize the result ArrayList are you doing it?

Comment: listOfRequests = new ArrayList<SingleData>(); this is made before

Comment: Post the exception you are getting in getView()

Comment: Thank you Trickster. The problem was that the listAcivity class doesn't need a reference to a list it only needs a setListAdpater (if you're not using a custom list), but i didn't know that... of cours it's still not working... but for other reason i immagine... i will post it now...

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand onPostExecute to work is that it takes in a result object that is passed in from doInBackground(). So unless, you are returning that result in your doinbackground and then passing it to your RequestAdapter that way, you will get the NullPointer. Where are you initializing your result member? in OnCreate?

```
 protected List<SingleData> doInBackground(Void... reuslt) {
          ..... 
         ....
       ///Do some stuff

            return result;
          }
   }


private class DownloadTheImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<SingleData>> {

private Context _ctx;

public DownloadTheImages(Context ctx) {
    _ctx = ctx;
}
```

Comment: I'm passing a return List<SingleData> at the end of DoinBackground. In the debug section, the breakpoint is giving me 21 correct objct before calling the adapter inside onPostExecute, so the List<SingleData> is correctly pass to onPostExecute... i think..

Comment: Oh ok, I was a bit confused because I didn't see the code for your doInbackground. As the guy below said though I would inflate my listview, instantiate and set my adapter in onCreate rather than in onPostExec....Any reason why you're doing it that way anyways?

Comment: but now following these advices i have error as soon as i start the activity

Comment: 10-20 15:48:04.885: E/AndroidRuntime(997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mimiedesign.dingle/com.mimiedesign.dingle.PictureStreamViewer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-20 15:48:04.885: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    10-20 15:48:04.885: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    10-20 15:48:04.885: E/AndroidRuntime(997):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

Comment: ListView mainLV = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  listOfRequests = new ArrayList<SingleData>();
  adapter = new RequestAdapter(_context, R.layout.single_row, listOfRequests);
  mainLV.setAdapter(adapter);
  new DownloadTheImages(_context).execute();

Comment: Hmm..have you instantiated your _context variable before using it?

Comment: i have a _context = this; after super.OnCreate

Comment: ok... mainLV is null.... so if i use ListActivity base class what is the id of the listView inside it?... isn't it android.R.id.list?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys... the problem moved somewhere else... I was using a ListActivity that doesn't need a findViewById on anything... I just needed to use setListAdapter... thank you